# What's the best wiki software for me to modify for a proof-of-concept?

Tags: open-source, wiki

My apologies if this is too subjective of a question.

I have a theory about wiki design; specifically, how a particular change to the model embodied by the wiki software would make the wiki revision process more closely resemble the open-source development process and thereby reap benefits that the current wiki model does not.

I would like to develop a proof-of-concept of this modified wiki design by finding an existing wiki package that I can alter.  However, it's hard for me to find the optimum balance between the features I need and what my programming skills are actually up to.

I need wiki software that:

1. is open-source.  This is a pretty non-negotiable requirement because otherwise I won't be able to test any modified version under real-world conditions.
2. implements revisions according to the standard wiki model.
3. implements security-protected user accounts.  The security does not have to be defense-agency-grade, but it does have to take reasonable steps to see that no one can access the abilities available to an account except the owner of that account.  (It's great if the software also allows anonymous and/or IP-based editing, but not crucial.)
4. is as simple and clean in design as possible.  It's an extra bonus if it's written in Python or a similarly user-friendly language.
5. is as fully-featured as possible within the above constraints.

What do you recommend?

Comment: I may not have any useful recommendations, but check this page out. It should help you find this balance of features: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MoinMoin](http://moinmo.in/) seems to meet your requirements (it's in Python, and under GPL; it's pretty feature-rich, including access control as you require).

Answer (score 0):

Do you like Wikipedia? If so go for http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki It is **PHP**